# Multiple posting software for social media

Tags: facebook, social-networks, google+

I've looked at a raft of web apps such as [Hootsuite](https://hootsuite.com/). They have this in common:

1. Expensive to use.
2. Designed for people who are posting to hundreds or thousands of sites/groups/pages.
3. Detailed analytics.

I'm looking for something cheaper, simpler, and with the single function of being able to schedule a post to a group page I don't own.

And I want to run it from my desktop, not from someone's server.

#### Background

I looked at using Facebook's advertising system which is quite reasonable -- except that it cannot target my niche market which is very very narrow (farm and acreage owners within 2 hours travel). I have found a set of groups that cover this niche.

*"So you are looking for a Spam tool eh?"* No.

Do I want to advertise on Facebook groups?  Yes.

But my usual definition of spam is:

1. It has no relevance to the audience.
2. It takes little notice of objections.
3. It is repetitious.
4. It acts without permission.

My interactions with these groups:

1. I act to give information.
2. When people are offended, I immediately apologize and seek clarification of guidelines from the group.
3. I do not repost at all on the same group.
4. I have permission from the group owner to post in a reasonable manner.

Comment: How expensive is too expensive? Or how much may the software cost?

Comment: For which sites do you need this? According to the tags, Facebook and Google+. Any others? -- And which operating system do you use (given that you want to run it from your desktop)?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I didn't find a **standalone application** that you can schedule the post on multiple social media accounts. If someone already found it, I hope it will post the application soon here.

I recommend the **web application** which opposes the question above. You can use **[Buffer](https://bufferapp.com)** application, they offer you start for free. You can ***schedule the post*** as much as you want. The application also gives you the chance to ***connect the social media*** not only Facebook but also Twitter, LinkedIn, and soon.

If you want on the another case, you can start the another plan. The another plan gives you more features, like unlimited scheduled posts and rich analytics for your posts, [more info](https://bufferapp.com/business).